# Howto connect to smartphone via WiFi while still using LAN on Windows7

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

My main network runs on LAN. My smartphone can't be integrated into this network. But I want to run a server (e.g. FTP/SMB) on my smartphone and want to connect to it via WiFi.

So on my notebook I want to use LAN and WiFi in parallel. Both adapters are in different networks. And I don't need any bridging between both networks.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has an inbuilt hotspot feature your best bet would be to use that and connect your laptop to your phone via the hotspot.

If the phone doesn't have a hotspot feature, you will need access to a wireless router of some sorts.